# How to include css stylesheet inside partial jsp?

Tags: java, css, jsp, jakarta-ee, jsp-fragments

jspf header:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/style.css">
    <title>Serendipity Book Shop</title>
  </head>
```

Partial jsp code:

```
<div id="indexLeftColumn">
  <div class="categoryBox">
    <a href="#"><span class="categoryLabelText">Science Fiction</span></a>
  </div>
  ...
</div>
```

I would like to split *assets/css/style.css* and create partial css and include it as css blocks into their respective html files.

In Django I used to do:

```
{% block css %} ... {% endblock %}
```

The only way that I found is to use style inside the html body:

```
<style> ... </style>
```

Is there a better way doing it?

Comment: Why not just make multiple CSS files and include them via `<link rel...`?

Comment: I was thinking about it but that usually goes inside the html <head>

Comment: That's the best way to do it. Putting style blocks in the body and putting style attributes directly on the tags is not recommended.

Comment: Would it be <body> ... <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" property="stylesheet" href="path/to/part/css" /> ... </body> ?

Comment: make different css files and include them on your page using the JSP include directive

Answer (score 0):

As reported in some comments it would be advised to have multiple *CSS* files, chunks of *assets/css/style.css*, and include the ones you want into your JSP files.

Otherwise, I can recommend using [Apache Tiles](http://tiles.apache.org/) which is a templating framework that let you define multiple layouts for different JSP files **including multiple assets**. It will be up to you to choose how to decouple and manage your layouts.

Even though this framework is not handled within a great community and have slightly pure examples for advanced topics but you can easilly get your self out with a good template when it comes to some basic layout.